# Best Practice ETL with Dataflow and Lookup

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

What's the best practice to implement a standard streaming ETL process which writes fact and some smaller dimensional tables to BigQuery?

I'm trying to understand how to handle the following things:

- How to do a simple dimension lookup in a streaming pipeline?
- In case the answer is sideInput - how to handle lookups for values that don't exist yet in the dimension? How to update the sideInput?

Comment: Can you give a bit more information on what you are trying to do?  Side inputs may be the answer; more information is available here: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/par-do#side-inputs-and-windowing

Comment: @danielm the main question when using side inputs was on how a side input in a streaming job would be updated with new values streaming in from the main input.
Example: a fact streams in with a new customer id which doesn't exist yet in the side input. We want to add it to the sideInput so the next fact actually doesn't think it's still missing.

Comment: That's an interesting question Jimmy. Let me check that - and sorry that we took so long to look atthis.

Answer (score 1):

When side inputs receive late data on a specific window, they will be recomputed. If you do the lookup after this, then you'll be able to see the element in the side input.

Currently, the Beam model does not include semantics for re-triggering of the ParDo that consumes the side input, so you'd need to somehow make sure to (re)do de lookup after the side input has been computed.

Comment: Yeah I was hoping there was some easy way to "trigger" a rerun of a side Input. For now it seems it's easiest to lookup the data outside of the pipeline and provide it as a parameter when creating the ParDo.

Comment: Glad you could figure a way out - we'll look into perhaps adding those semantics.

Comment: What would be the approach if I stream data into the fact-, and dimensional tables at the same time? I want to enrich the fact table with the corresponding surrogate key that has been applied to the rows in the dimensional tables. to my knowledge, using BigQuery as a lookup table for finding the correct surrogate keys is not optimal.